# The poisition of "only" in the sentence

Tags: grammar, gerunds

Is the written sentence correct?

> He woke up completely and was feeling like reading a book, but the only one book to be read in the room was the Bible.

Comment: *Only* with a singular head entails singularity, so the quantifier *one* is redundant. (In fact, *only* is etymologically "one-like".) Note that *feel* is a stative verb, so it is not cast in the progressive unless you wish to emphasize that the feeling was transient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As StoneyB mentions in his comment, you can have "one" or "only" but not both.

> ... but the **only** book in the room was the Bible

However you can use the expression "one and only" to emphasize there is *only one*

> ... but the **one and only** book in the room was the Bible

You may be confused by the expression "only one".  Here "one" is a pronoun, not an adjective, and frequently takes the article "the":

> There are many books in the world, but the Bible was **the only one** in the room.

Also, "feel" usually implies a condition, not an action, and so most of the time you want to use the simple past, especially with narrative:

> He woke up and **felt** like reading a book.

This also improves the flow of the sentence, since both verbs have the same tense.

If the feeling is *transient* or if you are talking about a current, ongoing situation, then the progressive is fine.

> **I'm feeling** frustrated at the world a lot these days.
>
> She **was feeling** ill, so she stayed home and took a nap, hoping to feel better after she woke.